# What is the "Ignoring InnerClasses attribute" warning output during compilation?

Tags: android, compiler-warnings

I am new to Android and am using the `Ical4j` library for parsing ICS (Outlook calendar) files.

However, when I build my application in Eclipse, the following warning appears many times in the console:

> [2010-07-22 15:58:31 - Google Calendar Upload] warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably produced by a broken compiler.)

Which implications does this have? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is quite common when including jar files. Although the warning isn't anything to worry about if you are just using the API normally, you should be able to get rid of them by compiling ical4j yourself from source within Eclipse (either build a new jar, or just drop the source into your own source folder). Though I should stress that unless you actually get problems, this isn't something to worry about.

Comment: More detail plis, I dont understand what to do =/

Comment: @zhelon, unless it's causing you problems you don't really have to do anything.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress this warning? I'm geting heavily spammed by it.

Comment: @Malabarba do you have access to the source? Rebuild it with a more recent version of Java.

Comment: I still get this error message from libraries that have been built with JDK-1.7. Need some better instructions on removing or a way to quench the warning if it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 31):

If your app and your libraries have all been built with a new JDK (7+) and you are still getting this, then you can fix this problem by telling Proguard to keep the enclosing method attribute. Just add the following to your Proguard rules:

`-keepattributes EnclosingMethod`

Comment: no effect for me. what helped me was Cleaning the Project then Make Project.

Comment: This warning quoted by OP is coming from DEX, not ProGuard; I'm compiling test sources and I don't see how adding a ProGuard option, which is not used would help.

Comment: This works for code wrote in the project but doesn't work for jar libraries already obfuscated without this configuration. But I guess there is probably no way to improve that.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error when using ksoap2 library.

To get rid of it I downloaded [DJ Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/) to decompile the .jar file to .java files.
After that i compiled the .java files to a .jar file using eclipse.

Comment: You can just recompile from source rather than decompiling. It is on github. Also this problem comes from ksoap2-android being compiled for java 1.3.

Comment: I didn't found the right sources for the version i was using but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Update build tools and support libraries to the same version

Comment: Though this answer could have more detail about `why` this would help this is not a wrong answer... It just doesn't help a lot understanding the problem