# Avoiding Android app failing to compile when given lots of jars?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse and attempting to build my Android app. It's mostly worked fine, but as I add libraries, the compiler slows down. Now that I've added the GeoTools WFS plugin (and that alone, avoiding any jars I don't need) Eclipse slows down so much during a build, that it crashes and never completes. It works fine in a normal Java application. It takes only a second or two. But in an Android one, it can take 15 minutes of unresponsiveness before finally dying.

At first, I thought it may have to do with the “Ignoring InnerClasses attribute” warning I asked about at ["Ignoring InnerClasses attribute" warning is killing Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5591811/637087), but now I'm not sure, as solving that problem hasn't helped (and some of the libraries don't have their source available anyway).

I have also tried increasing Eclipse's heap space, but after giving it 2 gig, all it did was take five times as long to crash.

Does anyone know what's going on and/or how to solve it?