# Android gradle and roboguice 2.0 warnings

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After adding a dependency on roboguice 2.0 I get a lot of warnings like the bellow when running `gradle build`

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.sf.cglib.util.StringSwitcher$Generator$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

My `build.gradle` file looks like:

buildscript {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
            }
        }

```
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile files('/libs/android-support-v4.jar')

        compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 16
        }
    }
```

I know they are just warnings but I am beginner experimenting with this new build system and I want to make sure I am on the right track.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is noting to worry about you can get rid of the warnings by recompiling the jar from source. More information @ [What is the “Ignoring InnerClasses attribute” waning outputted during compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308010/what-is-the-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-waning-outputted-during-compilatio)

Comment: I will mark this as answer, but recompiling android build tools from source is not something I am looking forward on doing.

Comment: You do not need to recompile the android build tools, but rather the jar with this class net.sf.cglib.util.StringSwitcher.

Comment: What causes this necessity?  I have to add the Android `gradle` JAR to my project as a library instead of using Maven (don't ask, not my decision).  When I do, I receive > 200 of those messages.  So, each time I update the version of the JAR I will have to recompile it???

Comment: @JackStraw you do not need to recompile the jar if you can live with the warnings in your output. The project should build fine without recompiling the jar.