# Android DX Warnings Cause Crash

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, dalvik, dx

The android project I am working on in Eclipse uses maven to bring in JAR files. One of the jar files has native *.so files in it causing this error to pop up then a memory size issue crashing the IDE.

> [2014-03-26 08:42:23 - **] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute
>   for an anonymous inner class (org.ibex.nestedvm.util.Sort$1) that
>   doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class
>   was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern
>   .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class
>   from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any
>   "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is
>   that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate
>   that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> [2014-03-26 08:43:10 - **] The library 'sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar'
>   contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
>
> [2014-03-26 08:43:10 - **] The following libraries were found:
>
> [2014-03-26 08:43:10 - **]  - native/Linux/amd64/libsqlitejdbc.so
>
> [2014-03-26 08:43:10 - **]  - native/Linux/i386/libsqlitejdbc.so
>
> [2014-03-26 08:43:10 - **]  - native/Mac/i386/libsqlitejdbc.jnilib
>
> [2014-03-26 08:43:10 - **]  - native/Mac/x86_64/libsqlitejdbc.jnilib

Some SO comments recommended a recompile of the JAR to include no *.so files and have proper target as to remove the first warning.
[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308010/what-is-the-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-waning-outputted-during-compilatio/3308059#3308059)

I did what any person usually does at first and upgraded my ADT and Eclipse tools. Now I get the following warning:

> [2014-03-26 14:17:08 - **] Dx  trouble writing output: already
>   prepared

The IDE no longer crashes (I upgraded the eclipse ini file to boost memory 4 fold) and previous warnings have disappeared. ADT is version now 22.6.2 and was previously 22.6.0.

**So here's the question: Is this a true fix or is something masked now?**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessary `Linux` and `Mac` in your development time, remove these folders form `sqlite-jdbc-xxx.jar`. Open `jar` file by using zipping tools and remove it.

When you need these package, add again into the `jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will say this, I moved to Android Studio a few weeks ago and the problem went away (or was hidden). However, if someone can confirm this later on I'll accept this as the answer.