# Android application not launching (on device or emulator)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have an Android application that used to work fine. I think the last piece of code I added was some sqlite database code. Now, when I run the application:

- Says "Launching Application (100%)" in the bottom, right corner.
  In the Progress tab, the progress bar is not filled in at all (for launching the application).
- Uses up all the allowed ram (760M)
- The application doesn't actually get installed on my device (I've also tried this without my device plugged in, and it doesn't make it to the screen to ask me which emulator I want to launch).

When I create a new Android application in the workspace the new application runs fine.

System Details:

- Eclipse 4.3 for Mac OS X (installed the latest version including the ADT in an attempt to fix the problem).
- Android Developer Tools. Build: v22.6.2-1085508
- OS X 10.8.5

Just let me know if I've left out any information and I'll add it in asap.

[Edit:] After leaving it running (not force-quitting), I get this error message:
[2014-06-25 10:07:53 - Application] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.ibex.nestedvm.util.Sort$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-06-25 10:18:10 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
[2014-06-25 10:18:10 - Application] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space

Comment: what's in your logcat?

Comment: Nothing application-specific.

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943712/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-heap-space

Comment: Fixed using: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308010/what-is-the-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-waning-outputted-during-compilatio/3308059#3308059](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308010/what-is-the-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-waning-outputted-during-compilatio/3308059#3308059)