# android Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class jar file issue

Tags: java, android, jar, java-me

i have used **lcrypto-j2me-144.jar**  jar file to encrypt the user name and password in my application it is running fine but when i look into console it is giving me , basically it is j2me jar file, please guide me to get rid of this issue.

```
Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Comment: I'm getting this same issue when trying to import dagger-compiler.

Comment: have you figured this one out?

Comment: i don't find any solution with eclipse IDE

Comment: This is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308010/what-is-the-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-warning-output-during-compilation/3308059#3308059

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just fyi, this can also happen when compiling for java 1.7 and the library have been through proguard, adding this will solve the problem when compiling the library:

`-keepattributes EnclosingMethod`

Comment: This won't help if occurs not by proguard.