# Proguard issue "Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"

Tags: android, proguard, android-support-library, android-proguard

I don't know how I can describe this issue. I searched a lot, but I didn't find any solution.

Also this solution did not help me [-keepattributes EnclosingMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30406817/3512164):

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:material-drawer')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:viewpagerindicator:2.4.3'
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

And the jar folder contains `ormlite-android-4.48.jar` and `ormlite-core-4.48.jar`.

Proguard File:

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-dontobfuscate

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**

#FOR APPCOMPAT 23.1.1:
-keep class !android.support.v7.view.menu.*MenuBuilder*, android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.* { *; }

# Required for crashlytics
#-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
#-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*

# Required for eventbus
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
}

# OrmLite uses reflection
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

# Keep the helper class and its constructor
-keep class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

# Keep all model classes that are used by OrmLite
# Also keep their field names and the constructor
-keep @com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable class * {
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField <fields>;
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField <fields>;
}

-keep public class org.codehaus.**
-keep public class java.nio.**

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.packagename.database.tables.** { *; }
-keep class com.packagename.models.apidata.** { *; }
-keep class com.packagename.models.data.** { *; }

## Nineolddroid related classes to ignore

-keep class com.nineoldandroids.animation.** { *; }
-keep interface com.nineoldandroids.animation.** { *; }
-keep class com.nineoldandroids.view.** { *; }
-keep interface com.nineoldandroids.view.** { *; }

-dontwarn okio.**
```

Error log:

```
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1) that doesn't come with an
(android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1) that doesn't come with an
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
(android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatJB$1) that doesn't come with an
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
(io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1) that doesn't come with an
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
(android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatKitKat$1) that doesn't come with an
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
(android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1) that doesn't come with an
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$3) that doesn't come with an
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
(android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatKK$1) that doesn't come with an
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatICS$1) that doesn't come with an
(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$4) that doesn't come with an
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$2) that doesn't come with an
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
(android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1) that doesn't come with an
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
(android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatLollipop$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
(com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$1) that doesn't come with an
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
(io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$2) that doesn't come with an
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type int using a local variable of type android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
```

Rest of error log:

```
Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.commit451/PhotoView/1.2.4/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/crashlytics-core/2.3.8/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs/commons/0.8.5.6/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs/core/0.8.5.6/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.viewpagerindicator/viewpagerindicator/2.4.3/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [/home/ibrahim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.4.0/5b72bf48563ea8410e650de14aa33ff69a3e8c35/okio-1.4.0.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/answers/1.3.6/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [/home/ibrahim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.nineoldandroids/library/2.4.0/e9b63380f3a242dbdbf103a2355ad7e43bad17cb/library-2.4.0.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/io.fabric.sdk.android/fabric/1.3.10/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/crashlytics/2.5.5/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [/home/ibrahim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.4/695b63d702f505b9b916e02272e3b6381bade7f/gson-2.4.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/beta/1.1.4/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [/home/ibrahim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library/1.0.19/a8f23f65fc1e522ee4a1a697ee569901a46741fa/library-1.0.19.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [/home/ibrahim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/2.5.2/7446d06ec8d4f7ffcc53f1da37c95f200dcb9387/picasso-2.5.2.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/recyclerview-v7/23.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.mikepenz/iconics/1.6.2/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/release/jars/2/1f/main.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/AppName.libraries/material-drawer/unspecified/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.2.0/jars/libs/internal_impl-23.2.0.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-vector-drawable/23.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/23.2.0/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.mikepenz/iconics-core/1.6.2/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [/home/ibrahim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/2.4.0/40340c0748190fe897baf7bffbc1b282734294e5/okhttp-2.4.0.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [/home/ibrahim/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/de.greenrobot/eventbus/2.4.0/ddd166d01b3158d1c00576d29f7ed15c030df719/eventbus-2.4.0.jar] (filtered)
  Copying resources from program jar [path/to/application/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar/library/1.1.4/jars/classes.jar] (filtered)
```

Comment: Hello, please do you remembrer the size of your `org.gradle.jvmargs=xxxx` ?

Comment: I have tried below solutions but it didn't worked out.Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629487/android-obfuscation-minifyenabled-true-not-working-in-both-debug-and-release  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try adding

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize
```

to the ProGuard config. That should fix the problem.

It's probable that incompatible optimizations are applied (that probably causes the last line of the error log).

If you want to allow optimizations, it's necessary to fine tune optimizations config with

```
-optimizations optimization_filter
```

option in ProGuard config.

Comment: Hmm, weird. What about the other module ':libraries:material-drawer', is it obfuscated? This problem often occurs when an obfuscated library is added to an app and the library is missing some attributes.

Comment: Try to skip optimizations `-dontoptimize`. It's possible that some incompatible optimizations are performed.

Comment: `-dontoptimize` worded thank you. Please edit your answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: Done. I added some more details to optimizations.

Comment: What if I want to avoid these warning on debug build, do I have to use proguard file?

Comment: I have tried above solution but it didn't worked out.Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629487/android-obfuscation-minifyenabled-true-not-working-in-both-debug-and-release  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 33):

> Adding these lines to proguard-rules.pro file fixed my issue.

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Comment: Is this relevant for debug builds?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I just tested it on my debug build and it removed the errors I had for the same issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky unless you've explicitly changed your `build.gradle` file, debug builds do not use ProGuard, so this is not relevant for debug builds. It doesn't make much sense (to me at least) to obfuscate debug builds, because it makes it harder to debug.

Comment: I have tried above solution but it didn't worked out.Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629487/android-obfuscation-minifyenabled-true-not-working-in-both-debug-and-release  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

I suggest `-dontwarn InnerClasses`

Comment: I have tried above solution but it didn't worked out.Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629487/android-obfuscation-minifyenabled-true-not-working-in-both-debug-and-release  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that often the cause for this problem is when [proguard-android.txt](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android.txt) file is not referenced in the project, as it contains the  correct configuration to avoid this issue:

```
# Preserve some attributes that may be required for reflection.
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
```

#### Solution

Make sure to add this file to your project, along with your own ProGuard configuration files, for example:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    setProguardFiles([getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'])
}
```

The file is contained in the SDK so your gradle build will pick it up automatically, you don't need to copy it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 problems here.

1) `Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class ......`

It's just a warning. If your code works properly you can ignore it by disabling Lint in the `.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

2) `translation error: attempt to set or access a value of type int using a local variable of type android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams`

This looks like in some place ProGuard optimizes variable allocation, but does it incorrectly.

Try to disable this optimization by adding the line below in your ProGuard file:

`-optimizations !code/allocation/variable`

Comment: Don't turn off lint just because of this one problem.

Comment: @tir38 Actually, this answer was very helpful for us.  Turning off lint allowed us to get a troublesome project building and running for a client.  We can investigate a more appropriate solution in the future, but for now turning off Lint was key to a timely response.

Comment: This is not applicable for debug builds.

Comment: Josh and Oleg are right: this works, and my app runs.  Can Android Studio/gradle give us some more specific information to action - like which jar file the offending classes are in?  This was preventing me from running my application in debug.

Answer (score 1):

Add `dex.force.jumbo=true` into your gradle.properties. It works for me.

Comment: What is "gradle.properties"? A file?

Comment: @PeterMortensen "gradle.properties" is a file locate at your project path

Comment: It works! And want to no if the config will mute my project's warning?

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved the problem was to use a newer version of jar. The clue was:

> This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler.

So i changed from:

```
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0'
```

to:

```
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score -2):

I resolved a similar issue by updating the compile SDK, target SDK version, and support libraries version.

Comment: to what version?