# Suppress gradle dependency warnings

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have dependency in my build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('3d.party.lib:1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

That contains warnings:

`Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class`

I guess that because of missing `-keepattributes InnerClasses` in proguard config of that library or whatever.

So I don't want to see it in my build log. Is there any gradle settings or build arguments to suppress it?

Comment: possible duplicate?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796144/progaurd-issue-warningignoring-innerclasses-attribute-for-an-anonymous-inner-c

Comment: I want to suppress this warnings for `debug` build without proguard

Comment: But it's simple. Did you try   **lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
}**
In gradle?