# Instabug for Android build warning

Tags: android, circleci, instabug

We have a gradle project that contains 4 modules: 1 library module and 3 android apps. To build our apps we use **circleCI**. We have also disabled predex-ing for the circleCI builds following [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips) guide.

Everything was great until I added **Instabug** to one of our projects. We have been reaching the circleCI 4GB limit ever since. On top of that, the project that has Instabug as a dependency will start the `preDex` gradle task, no matter what. To start a new build, we use the following command: `./gradlew assembleDebug -PpreDexEnable=false`.

The project that uses Instabug gets some warnings during build time like this:

> Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (com.instabug.library.b) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

I assume that we are reaching the 4 GB limit due to the preDex task that is started for the "Instabug project".

Does anyone has any idea on what's going on?

**Edit : gradle files**

root build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'de.hannesstruss:godot:0.2'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.11.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'de.hannesstruss.godot'
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'

def ciServer = 'CI'
def executingOnCI = "true".equals(System.getenv(ciServer))

ext {
    // preDexEnable property will come from the command line when circleCI is building the project.
    if (project.hasProperty('preDexEnable')) {
        project.ext.preDexLibs = project.properties['preDexEnable'].equals('true')
    } else {
        project.ext.preDexLibs = true // pre dexing should be true by default
    }

    buildTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

    developmentFlavor = {
        applicationId "${project.ext.appId}.${name}"
        versionName "${project.ext.verName}-${name}"
        minSdkVersion 15
        buildConfigField "String", "API_TYPE", "\"${name}\""
        resValue "string", "tray__authority", "${applicationId}.tray"
    }

    defaultLibraryFlavorConfig = {
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode project.ext.verCode
        versionName project.ext.verName

        multiDexEnabled true

        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${project.ext.gitSha}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
    }

    defaultFlavorConfig = defaultLibraryFlavorConfig << {
        applicationId project.ext.appId
        resValue "string", "tray__authority", "${applicationId}.tray"
    }

    defaultAndroidConfig = {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize executingOnCI ? "2048m" : "4g"
            jumboMode true
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        }

        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
    }

    project.ext.gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.projectDir).text.trim()

    project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        if ("com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = rootProject.ext.preDexLibs
        } else if ("com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
            project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = rootProject.ext.preDexLibs
        }
    }
}
```

dependencies.gradle

```
ext {
    kiosk = [
            dependencies: {
                compile project(':common')

                compile libraries.multidex
                compile libraries.viewPagerIndicator
                compile libraries.recyclerview
                compile libraries.volley
                compile libraries.instabug
                compile libraries.mixpanel
                compile libraries.loadToast
                compile(libraries.crashlytics) {
                    transitive = true;
                }

                compile libraries.dagger
                apt libraries.daggerCompiler
                provided libraries.javaxAnnotations
            }
    ]
}
```

kiosk module build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.6'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'http://archiva.instabug.com/repository/release' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

ext.verCode = versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
ext.verName = "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

ext.appId = 'care.smart.android.kiosk'

android defaultAndroidConfig << {

    defaultConfig defaultFlavorConfig << {
        minSdkVersion 21
        buildConfigField "String", "APP_NAME", "\"Android-Kiosk\""
    }

    productFlavors {
        realProduction {
            buildConfigField "String", "API_TYPE", '"prod"'
        }

//        dev developmentFlavor

    }


}

dependencies kiosk.dependencies
```

Comment: This is Kim from CircleCI. Could you post the same question on our support? We can give you better support there. Once you got the answer, you can post it back here. Thanks!

Comment: This is Hassan from Instabug. That warning is annoying, but it shouldn't be causing any problems. A related question on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308010/what-is-the-ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-warning-output-during-compilation/3308059). We'll be getting rid of that warning in a future release though. Regarding the preDex task, is this happening locally as well? or just on CircleCI?

Comment: It happens in both places, locally and circleCI.

Comment: I can't replicate this locally, can you add your root build.gradle to the question?

Comment: @HassanIbraheem I added the related gradle build files.

Comment: @HassanIbraheem any ideas?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to replicate the same configuration you posted with all plugins, dependencies and the library project. So far, I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior, but will try again. Is it possible to reproduce this on a simpler single Gradle project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no real answer to this question. But the `preDex` task was created due to `minSdkVersion 21`. Also, we couldn't limit ourselves to 4GB of RAM so we had to bump it up to 6GB.